# variances and bounds together

Tags: scala, generics

What I need is, let say, I have a List trait, and Value trait, and special lists store special Value types. I tried this, but line.value doesn't exist, and the reason is, it looks like prepend's type parameter is not the actual SingleValue class, but it is still a template. But why? thanks

```
sealed trait Value
case class SingleValue(value: Int) extends Value
case class DoubleValue(value1: Int, value2: Int) extends Value


trait List1  {
  def prepend[B <: Value](value: B): Int
}

case class SingleList1 extends List1 {

  def prepend[SingleValue](line: SingleValue): Int = {
    line.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SingleValue` in `def prepend[SingleValue](line: SingleValue)` is a *type parameter*, not a concrete type.

Like when you wrote `def prepend[B <: Value](value: B): Int`, you used `B` as a variable `def prepend[SingleValue]` has exactly the same meaning (except that variable name is different, but that's immaterial).

It is not very clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do here ... but, if I am guessing correctly, you want to parametrize the *class*, not the method:

```
   trait List1[B <: Value] {
      def prepend(b: B): Int
   }

   class SingleList extends List1[SingleValue] { 
      def prepend(sv: SingleValue) = sv.value
   }
```

**Update** So, if you want your `List1` to be covariant, as you mentioned in the comment, that won't work: if it did, then `SingleList` would be a subclass of `List1[Value]`, and therefore `prepend` would have to work with any `Value`, not just `SingleValue`, and it doesn't know how.

What you could do in that case, is define the specialized `prepend` method "on the side" and associate it with `List1` via an implicit conversion:

```
trait Lis1[+B <: Value]
    
object List1Ops { 
  implicit class SVL[T <: SingleValue](val l: List1[T]) extends AnyVal {
     def prepend(v: T) = v.value
  }
}
```

This let's you do both things like:

```
val svl = new List1[SingleValue]{}
println(svl.prepend(new SingleValue))
```

and

```
val l: List1[Value] = new List1[SingleValue]{} // still covariant
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. This is almost what I want to do, but I want to put a + before B, and that breaks it
PS: You are right, it was not very clear from my final post)

Comment: @barii to make it covariant you need to define prepend like this: `[A <: Value >: B](a: A): List1[A]` - However, at that point one can wonder if you are really whining much over just `List[Value]`

Comment: @barii see my update

Comment: @Dima, it still complains that "Covariant type B occurs in contravariant position in type B of value sv"

Comment: @baril Ugh, yeah ... that doesn't work, what was I thinking. :/
Ok, updated the answer again. How does this look?